# How to get the latest git tag on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, git-tag

I want to checkout the latest git tag on Windows.

I use the following command on Linux:

`` git checkout `git describe --tags --abbrev=0 origin/master` ``

Whats the equivalent for this command on Windows?

---

I tried using `for` & `set` to expand the backticked command into a variable for usage on the `git checkout`.

I started out with:

`for /f %a in ('git describe') do (echo %a)`.

It returns `v1.0.18-131-g792d5a2`. This works, but contains a bit too much information. I just need `v1.0.18`. That's why i'm trying to use `--abbrev=<n>` to suppress the long format and only show the closest tag.

When i added the arguments:

`for /f %a in ('git describe --tags --abbrev=0 origin/master') do (echo %a)`

it fails with: `fatal: Not a valid object name 0`. Not sure why...

---

Here is what i got so far:

`checkout-latest-tag.bat`

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ('git describe --tags --abbrev=0 origin/master') do (
   set LATEST_TAG=%%a
)
echo The latest tag is: %LATEST_TAG%

git checkout %LATEST_TAG%
```

It would be nice, if you could come up with a one-liner.

Comment: `for /f "delims=-" %a in ('git describe') do echo %a`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `^` to escape the offending `=`.

```
for /f %%a in ('git describe --tags --abbrev^=0 origin/master') do git checkout %%a
```

Comment: Oh didn't know about the caret operator. Works like charm! Thank you very much!